# Sobrescribir un objeto con otro objeto / Javascript

Tags: javascript, objeto, parametros

Buen dia Comunidad.!! Les pregunto una duda, ¿es posible que un objeto llamado objetoViejo transfiera todos los parametros a otro objeto llamado objetoNuevo?, si es el caso me podrian explicar como, de antemano gracias..

Comment: mirate esto https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

Comment: @hawks Esta bien, lo revisare.. Gracias por la pronta respuesta